# Why won't this sorting work

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Ok, so I wrote a method which should sort an `ArrayList` object. And it does... sort of. The object is an array of 20 random numbers, and after executing piece of code shown below I get the following result:

`[-7, -7, -7, -7, -7, -7, -7, -7, -7, -7, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 27, 27, 27]`

```
public static void sortArray (ArrayList<Integer> arrayToSort)
{
    int smallestNum;

    for (int j=0; j<arrayToSort.size(); j++)
    {
        smallestNum = arrayToSort.get(j);
        for (int i=j; i<arrayToSort.size(); i++)
        {
            if (arrayToSort.get(i)<=smallestNum)
            {
                smallestNum = arrayToSort.get(i);
            }
        }
        arrayToSort.set(j, smallestNum);
    }       
}
```

Comment: The result looks sorted for me.. What's the problem?

Comment: Why not use the `Collections.sort`? Besides, the result does look sorted to me. Or did you want a different ordering?

Comment: You wipe out the value at `j` and don't move it anywhere.

Comment: @Maroun Maroun Well, original array had more diverse numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute this line:

```
arrayToSort.set(j, smallestNum);
```

You are blowing away whatever was already in position j and losing it completely, that's why you see -7 duplicated until you get to where -7 was in the original array. You want to swap the smallest number into the jth position and the number in the jth position with where you grabbed the smallest number instead.

What you really want is more like:

```
public static void sortArray (ArrayList<Integer> arrayToSort)
{
    int smallestNum;
    int smallestPos;

    for (int j=0; j<arrayToSort.size(); j++)
    {
        smallestNum = arrayToSort.get(j);
        smallestPos = j;
        for (int i=j; i<arrayToSort.size(); i++)
        {
            if (arrayToSort.get(i)<=smallestNum)
            {
                smallestNum = arrayToSort.get(i);
                smallestPos = i;
            }
        }
        arrayToSort.set(smallestPos, arrayToSort.get(j);
        arrayToSort.set(j, smallestNum);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing j'th index value with i'th index value. So it creates a duplicate entry and also you will loose the previous value contained in j'th index.

Probably you need something like:

```
public static void sortArray (ArrayList<Integer> arrayToSort)
{
    int smallestNum;
    int smallestIndex;

    for (int j=0; j<arrayToSort.size(); j++)
    {
        smallestNum   = arrayToSort.get(j);
        smallestIndex = j;
        for (int i=j; i<arrayToSort.size(); i++)
        {
            if (arrayToSort.get(i)<=smallestNum)
            {
                smallestNum   = arrayToSort.get(i);
                smallestIndex = i;
            }
        }
        arrayToSort.set(smallestIndex, arrayToSort.get(j));
        arrayToSort.set(j, smallestNum);
    }       
}
```